# Quiero crear un menu que se cambie segun si el usuario esta logueado o no

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codig, que lo que quiero hacer es que a traves de las sesiones detectar si el usuario esta logueado o no, para asi mostrar una cosa u otra,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "Sesion no iniciada";
    // echo "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href=''>Mi perfil</a></li>";
  // echo "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/Onsen-Spa/includes/cerrar.php'>Cerrar sesion</a></li>";
}else {
  echo " Sesion iniciada";
//  echo " <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='login.php'>Iniciar Sesion</a></li>";
//   echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0' type='submit'><a href='Registro.php'>Registrarse</a></button>";
}
```

```
public function LogIn ($email,$pass){ 
    require('conexion.php');
    $nombre= "SELECT Nombre from Persona where Nombre= '".$email."'";//Obtener nombre de la persona que ingreso al sistema.
    $query = "SELECT count(*) as Contador from Cuenta  where Email= '".$email."' and Pass= '".$pass."' ";//Comprobar si el usuario existe
    $query2 = "SELECT Rol from Cuenta,Rol where Email = '".$email."' and Cuenta.id_rol = Rol.id_rol  "; //Comprobar el rol del usuario
    $consultaUser = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);//Consulta a la base de datos
    $consultaPass = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);//Consulta a la base de datos
    $consultaNombre = mysqli_query($conexion,$nombre);//Consulta a la base de datos
    $insercionArray = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaUser);//Converticion de lo recibido a un array
    $rol = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPass);//Converticion de lo recibido a un array
    $nombreArray = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaNombre);//Converticion de lo recibido a un array
    if ($insercionArray['Contador']==1) {//Comprobar si existe el mail que ingreso el usuario
     if ($rol['Rol']=='Cliente') {//Comprobar que rol tiene asignado el usuario en la BD, y segun cual sea se le redireccionara hacia su area especifica
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']= $nombreArray['Nombre'];
        header("Location:index.php");//Redireccion hacia area de usuario
     }else if ($rol['Rol']=='Administrativo') {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']= $nombreArray['Nombre'];
        header("Location:areas-usuarios/area-admin/index.php");//Redireccion hacia area de administrador
     }else {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']= $nombreArray['Nombre'];
        header("Location:areas-usuarios/area-gerente.php");//Redireccion hacia area de administrador
     }

    }else {
        echo "Ingrese los datos correctamente";
    }

}
```

Con este otro codigo si el usuario existe iniciaria sesion, osea la session de php empezaria, pero con el if del codigo de arriba no lo detecta

Comment: por lo general [`session_start();`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) va siempre al principio del script, o al menos antes de checkear `$_SESSION['algo']`: inicializa o rellena las variables de sesión php independientemente de si tu aplicación o usuario poseen una lógica de sesión login logout etc

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error?

Answer (score 0):

intenta con el siguiente codigo

```
if(!$_SESSION['username']){
echo "Sesion no iniciada";
    // echo "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href=''>Mi perfil</a></li>";
  // echo "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/Onsen-Spa/includes/cerrar.php'>Cerrar sesion</a></li>";
}else {
  echo " Sesion iniciada";
//  echo " <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='login.php'>Iniciar Sesion</a></li>";
//   echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0' type='submit'><a href='Registro.php'>Registrarse</a></button>";
}
```

Comment: una respuesta debe de estar comprobada y verificada

Comment: Me lo pone como variable indefinida y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Lukas4 tienes que incluir siempre el `session_start();`

Comment: Lo incluyo al principio siempre?

Comment: @Lukas4 si, tiene que estar al momento de iniciar el script

Comment: Poniendo el session_start() ya me funciono el codigo anterior

Comment: Perfecto, puedes votar por las respuesta de forma positiva y marcarla como correcta! Saludos.